# Magento: Fatal error: Call to a member function rewrite()

Tags: php, magento

I've enountering this error infrequently:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function rewrite() on a non-object in
>   /htdocs/public/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php
>   on line 165

I've seen the question asked a few times but for me it occurs every so often and isn't a constant error.

I have the exact same site running on localhost and didn't come across the error at all. It happens on pretty much any page. I've reset the permissions on everything to `777` while testing the site.

I've tried the following to try to fix it:

1. Go to `http://www.your-site/downloader` and Reinstall the package called `Lib_Varien`
2. The usual clear the cache in `var`
3. Permissions on anything `777`

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: An Apache restart might help too

Comment: Good call, will ask the crowd with WHM access to give it a reboot as unforetunately I don't have it.

Comment: @scrowler no luck there, thanks. As per my comment below to the a reply -I'm starting to think that because I've installed the site in a subdirectory of another Magento installation that that might be causing the issue. Maybe the staging site is using the main site's var directory instead? The live site is running 1.6 and the staging site is 1.9

Answer (score 2):

Per [this old Magento Stack Overflow question on the same subject](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8634/fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-rewrite-on-a-non-object-after-upgrade/8643#8643), the most likely reason is a stale Magento cache, **and/or** Magento not having write access to your system's `var` folder, which can confuse Magento as to where it can find the configured cache.

For reasons too myriad and varied to speculate on in a single Stack Overflow answer, your system either can't find the class alias `core/url_rewrite_request` in your configuration, or can't instantiate that model class.  Figure out why, and you'll solve your problem.

**Update**: I know you think you checked the permissions --- but check the permissions again, and check that Magento's using the `var` that you think it is.  Some debugging here ought to help

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config/Options.php
public function getVarDir()
{
    //$dir = $this->getDataSetDefault('var_dir', $this->getBaseDir().DS.'var');
    $dir = isset($this->_data['var_dir']) ? $this->_data['var_dir']
        : $this->_data['base_dir'] . DS . self::VAR_DIRECTORY;
    if (!$this->createDirIfNotExists($dir)) {
        $dir = $this->getSysTmpDir().DS.'magento'.DS.'var';
        if (!$this->createDirIfNotExists($dir)) {
            throw new Mage_Core_Exception('Unable to find writable var_dir');
        }
    }
    return $dir;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, the var directory is writeable and the files do exist that contain the class alias both the config and php with the class. I'm starting to think that because I've installed the site in a subdirectory of another Magento installation that that might be causing the issue. Maybe the staging site is using the main site's var directory instead? The live site is running 1.6 and the staging site is 1.9

Comment: Updated question with some additional debugging tips.

Comment: Cheers Alan! How do I access the result of that method?

Comment: If I can find out what Mage::getRoot() is returning that would be a start.

Comment: If I delete the cache it doesn't even try to recreate it too.

Comment: Just drop from var_dump($dir)'s in there temporarily

Comment: Cool and how do I access the result of the method? Run in through ssh or..? Sorry not to sure about how to go about getting it. Thanks!